# Problem writing a snippet containing Emacs Lisp code

Tags: emacs, elisp, code-snippets

I've been trying to make use of a cool feature of YASnippet: write snippets containing embedded Emacs Lisp code. There is a snippet for rst-mode that surrounds the entered text with "=" that is as long as the text such as in

`====`

`Text`

`====`

Based on this snippet, I decided to slightly modify it (with Elisp) so that it comments out these three lines depending on the major mode you are in (I thought that such a snippet would be useful to organize the source code). So I wrote this:

```
${1:`(insert comment-start)`} ${2:$(make-string (string-width text) ?\-)}
$1 ${2:Text}
$1 ${2:$(make-string (string-width text) ?\-)}

$0
```

This code works relatively well except for one problem: the indentation of these three lines gets mixed up, depending on the major mode I'm in (e.g., in emacs-lisp-mode, the second and the third lines move more to the right than the first line).

I think the source of the problem might have something to do with what comes after the string `${1:` on the first line. If I add a character, I have no problem (i.e., all three lines are correctly aligned at the end of the snippet expansion). If I add a single space after this string, the misalignment problem still continues though.

So my question is: do you know of any way of rewriting this snippet so that this misalignment does not arise?  Do you know what's the source of this behaviour?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Writing snippets](http://yasnippet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/snippet-development.html#yas-indent-line):

> ### yas/indent-line
>
> The variable yas/indent-line controls the indenting. It is bound to 'auto by default, which causes your snippet to be indented according to the mode of the buffer it was inserted in.
>
> Another variable yas/also-auto-indent-first-line, when non-nil does exactly that :-).
>
> To use the hard-coded indentation in your snippet template, set this variable to fixed.
>
> To control indentation on a per-snippet basis, see also the directive # expand-env: in Writing Snippets.
>
> For backward compatibility with earlier versions of YASnippet, you can also place a $> in your snippet, an (indent-according-to-mode) will be executed there to indent the line. This only takes effect when yas/indent-line is set to something other than 'auto.

```
for (${int i = 0}; ${i < 10}; ${++i})
{$>
$0$>
}$>
```

Comment: Shame on me I've missed that! Setting the variable "yas/indent-line" to "fixed" totally solved my problem. Thanks a lot Chen Levy for pointing that out.